# Existence of surjective continuous function $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove or disprove whether there exists a surjective continuous function $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, I would say no, since such a function would have to increase unboundedly and decrease unboundedly at the same time for $x\to1$ but I'm having a hard time actually proving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is such a function. Consider $g:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by formula
$$g(x) = x\cdot \sin(x)$$
Then consider any continuous bijection $h:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$. For instance take
$$h(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$$
Define $f = g\cdot h$.

**Remark.**

There are no such $f$ which are bijective. Indeed, suppose that such function exists. Let $f(0) = r\in \mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$f(\left(0,1)\right) = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{r\}$$
is a continuous image of a connected space. Hence it is connected. But clearly $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{r\}$ is disconnected. This is a contradiction.

Comment: How did you deduce that $f\bigl((0,1)\bigr)=\mathbb R\setminus\{r\}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for pointing out mistake.

Comment: You're welcome (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't a function increase and decrease unboundedly? Although this may seem impossible, it is actually quite easy to find examples of such functions. For example

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x} \sin \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$

satisfies your condition. It is obviously continuous, and

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}\frac{1}{1-x}=\infty$$

which implies that

$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$

oscillates an infinite number of times as $x$ approaches $1$. Since the magnitude of $f(x)$ goes to infinity, this is enough to prove the proposition. In fact, if $g(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0,1)$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}g(x)=\infty$$

then

$$f(x)=g(x)\sin(g(x))$$

satisfies the conditions.